# What is the best way to download image from url in Xamarin ios?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, webclient, system.net.webexception

I need to download Open street map tile for every panning and pinch zooming. I have used WebClient for downloading image from Uri. But I am getting “An HttpWebRequest was added to the connection group queue because the connection linit was reached and soon,I am getting System.Net.WebException in Xamarin iOS. But I am doing the same in Xamarin.Android, where images are downloaded comparatively better than the Xamarin iOS.

```
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        byte[] imageBytes = null;
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://tile.openstreetmap.org/" + Scale.ToString() + "/" + i.ToString() + "/" + j.ToString() + ".png");
        imageBytes = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(uri);
```

Answer (score 2):

On iOS we can use [NSUrlSession](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSUrlSession/) to download images, this may be more helpful for you. You can refer to the code below for the usage:

```
NSUrlSession session = NSUrlSession.SharedSession;
var dataTask = session.CreateDataTask(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl("yourUrl")), (data, response, error) =>
{
    if (response != null)
    {
        DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() =>
        {
            MyImageView.Image = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
        });
    }
});

dataTask.Resume();
```

Comment: can you share a more complete example?  in how to use it